# Which superglobals are affected by magic_quotes_gpc = 1?

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

By looking at the name of this directive one may think that `magic_quotes` are only applied to `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` superglobals but there is [one perturbing comment on the PHP Manual](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php#47733):

> Please note, that when
>   `magic_quotes_gpc` is set not only
>   `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_COOKIE`
>   arrays values are slashed. Actually
>   every string value in `$GLOBALS` array
>   is slashed, ie.
>   `$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['PATH_INFO']` (or
>   `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`).

Can anyone confirm that this is true? Are the superglobals `$GLOBALS`, `$_SERVER`, `$_FILES`, `$_SESSION` and `$_ENV` affected as well?

One more question, if I iterate `stripslashes()` over the `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` arrays do I also need to iterate through the `$_REQUEST` array? Or are the changes automatically reflected?

Comment: Why the down-vote? It's a perfectly legitimate question...

Comment: I recommend you just test it yourself. Should be quite easy. Also, try to see if you can disable magic_quotes in php settings or a .htaccess file. Much easier.

Comment: To rely on magic_quotes and addslashes and stripslashes is a serious flaw in security. I always turn of magic quotes. If I can't eg. I don't have control over the installation my scripts detect it and die. use the correct function for the job, filter all input from all user accessible inputs, eg. use mysql_real_escape_string for variables passed to mysql or use prepared statements or better yet stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run some tests on `LightTPD 1.4.20` and `PHP 5.3.0` with `magic_quotes_gpc = On` and `$_SERVER` wasn't altered (at least `[SERVER_NAME] => local'host` didn't). `$_SESSION` also isn't affected by magic_quotes.

`$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` and `$_REQUEST` were affected (and their `$GLOBALS` counterparts).

Also, the **changes in the `GPC` superglobals aren't automatically reflected in `$_REQUEST`**.

As for the `$_FILES` and `$_ENV` superglobals I'm not able to test them ATM.

---

I've finally ran this test and, to my surprise, both `$_FILES` and `php://input` **are** affected.

Answer (score 2):

Either way i'd advise you not to rely on GPC as it has been deprecated on newer PHP versions...

It may not be too relevant for your question but on the raised issue of SQL security alternatives i usually use prepared statements + mysql_real_escape_string for MySQL.

To make it close to perfect it involves a couple of functions as it also should support integer, boolean and null values but you can take a look at the source code on the Database and Database_mysql classes on [NaturePhp](http://naturephp.org) .

Comment: I'm not relying on magic_quotes, I'm just working around them **iff** magic_quotes_gpc exists **and** is on. You got it wrong on NaturePHP (you assume every variable passed is coming from GPCR) but it's a nice project nonetheless, congrats. =)

Comment: Thanx, i'll check it out and correct it for the next version :)