# Best method of disabling php magic quotes without php.ini or .htaccess

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

I am needing to write portable code that will run on a shared server with `magic_qoutes_gpc` enabled and I am unable to change that in php.ini or .htaccess. (the server is running php 5.2)

It seems there are numerous functions to stripslaches from all of the `$_GET`, `$_POST` etc superglobals but I'm not sure which is the best. Also some comments [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) seem to say that the keys also have slashes added which need to be stripped as well. So should I use the one on the PHP website:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
             unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

or something like this: (from this answer: [PHP - Shorter Magic Quotes Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077711/php-shorter-magic-quotes-solution))

```
function strip_slashes_recursive(&$value) {
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        $value = strip_slashes($value);
    } else {
        foreach (array_keys($value) as $key) {
            $arrayValue = strip_slashes_recursive($value[$key]);
            unset($value[$key]);
            $value[strip_slashes($key)] = $arrayValue;
        }
    }
}

foreach (array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST) as &$array) {
    strip_slashes_recursive($array);
}
// don't forget to unset references or it can lead to very nasty bugs
unset($array);
```

or even something like this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function undoMagicQuotes($array, $topLevel=true) {
        $newArray = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if (!$topLevel) {
                $key = stripslashes($key);
            }
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $newArray[$key] = undoMagicQuotes($value, false);
            }
            else {
                $newArray[$key] = stripslashes($value);
            }
        }
        return $newArray;
    }
    $_GET = undoMagicQuotes($_GET);
    $_POST = undoMagicQuotes($_POST);
    $_COOKIE = undoMagicQuotes($_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = undoMagicQuotes($_REQUEST);
}
```

Can someone explain the pros/cons of each approach and/or a totally different approach and how thorough they are and if they strip slashes from the key as well as the value.

(also is this method any good: [PHP: how to (correctly) remove escaped quotes in arrays when Magic Quotes are ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133026/php-how-to-correctly-remove-escaped-quotes-in-arrays-when-magic-quotes-are-on))
(and also it seems like all of these methods are incomplete as they don't strip slashes from all the affected superglobals [Which superglobals are affected by magic_quotes_gpc = 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024150/which-superglobals-are-affected-by-magic-quotes-gpc-1))

Comment: Pithy answer: Move to a half-decent hosting service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another one mostly from [PHP: how to (correctly) remove escaped quotes in arrays when Magic Quotes are ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133026/php-how-to-correctly-remove-escaped-quotes-in-arrays-when-magic-quotes-are-on) but with my own changes:

```
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function unMagicQuotify($array) {
        $fixed = array();
        foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                $fixed[stripslashes($key)] = unMagicQuotify($val);
            } else {
                $fixed[stripslashes($key)] = stripslashes($val);
            }
        }
        return $fixed;
    }

    $_GET = unMagicQuotify($_GET);
    $_POST = unMagicQuotify($_POST);
    $_COOKIE = unMagicQuotify($_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = unMagicQuotify($_REQUEST);
    $_FILES = unMagicQuotify($_FILES);
}
```

**Pro's**

- They work for both arrays and single variables
- Does strip the key
- Does not use references

**Con's**

- May change the order of variables

Note the inclusion of $_FILES as magic quotes also affects it.
As for reading a file (file_get_contents) and/or using php://input I couldn't tell whether magic quotes affects them, but you would have to stripslashes() as and when you are reading them and would not be able to do something like this. I didn't manage to check $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA but it isn't populated by default so things should be ok leaving it out.

Answer (score 0):

*First Method*

***Pro's***

- They work for both arrays and single variables
- Does strip the key

***Con's***

- The code is too long for what it needs to be

*Second Method*

***Pro's***

- They work for both arrays and single variables

***Con's***

- The code is too long for what it needs to be
- Does not strip the key

*Third Method*

***Pro's***

- They work for both arrays and single variables
- Does strip the key

***Con's***

- The code is too long for what it needs to be

I've been using this, which works ok (Found it in osTicket, I love open source):

```
function strip_slashes($var){
    return is_array($var)?array_map('strip_slashes',$var):stripslashes($var);
}


if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST = strip_slashes($_POST);
    $_GET = strip_slashes($_GET);
    $_REQUEST = strip_slashes($_REQUEST);
    $_COOKIE = strip_slashes($_COOKIE);
}
```

***Pro's***

- They work for both arrays and single variables

***Con's***

- Does not strip the keys

I've never come across the need to strip the keys as well though. Many open source libraries don't do it (e.g Wordpress, osTicket). Generally I only use name for $_POST and $_GET data that will never be escaped.

Comment: sorry, can you explain the pros and cons of each individual method compared to each other rather than as a whole, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "In the Simplest way:...."
Does your method remove slashes from keys as well as values?

Comment: This Format class, is this in the PHP library?

Comment: @phant0m Oops, no its not, its in a class in osTicket. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: you have both "Does strip the keys" and "Does not strip the keys" in the Con's section

Comment: Yeah sorry, to begin with I thought they didn't strip the key, then forgot to move it to the Pro section.

Comment: It turns out the last one in the list is no good because php does add \ to top level keys: e.g if you call magicquotetest.php?a'b[c'd]=e'f&a'b[g'h]=i'j&k'l=m'n and var_dump($_GET) you get:
`array(2) {
  ["a\'b"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["c\'d"]=>
    string(4) "e\'f"
    ["g\'h"]=>
    string(4) "i\'j"
  }
  ["k\'l"]=>
  string(4) "m\'n"
}`

Comment: on the plus side it doesn't use references

Comment: @tom see my updated question with a new method, what do you think?

Comment: I like it. Seems like the best way to go.

Comment: Do you think I should post it as an answer and accept it or wait to see if there are any more comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of slashes by performing this:

```
$_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes', $_REQUEST);
```

I think it's easier and makes code smaller and more laconic.

I'm sure you know about what problems could appear while using the magic quotes directive (here is an article http://www.sitepoint.com/magic-quotes-headaches/). But IMO it's better for you to move your apps to another hosting provider in case that your current provider can't turn magic quotes off. Also, it's not very good idea to use an outdated version of PHP.

Comment: but it doesn't remove slashes from keys does it?